# Variable might not have been initialized error in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class dice
{
  private int times;
  private int roll;
  private int side;
  Random roller = new Random();   

  public void setTimes(int sides)
  {
    times = sides;
  }

  public void setSides(int die)
  {
    side = die;
  }

  public int getRoll()
  { 
    int total; //here it is
    int c = 0;
    while (c <= times)
    {
      c = c + 1;
      int rol = 0;
      roll = roller.nextInt(side) + 1;
      rol = rol + roll;
      total = rol; //here it is initialized
    }
    return total; //here it says variable not initialized
  }
}
```

Comment: Your initialization occurs inside a conditional statement.  What happens if the condition isn't met?

Comment: Hey, you should select one of these answers as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've *declared* it without *initializing* it.  Give it an initial value before the while loop so the compiler is sure the variable doesn't contain garbage.

```
int total = 0;
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! but now i have another problem. I post another question.

Comment: @Mac: Can you mark an answer as "Accepted" please? (Just click the green check mark next to the answer that helped you the most.  It doesn't have to be this one.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The inside of a while loop isn't guaranteed to execute - for example, if `times` is less than zero from a programming mistake. The compiler knows this, so it won't count on the while loop when figuring out whether `total` was initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to initialize local variables in Java.

```
int total = 0; //here it is
int c = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have another question about the loop.

Comment: You aren't required to initialize them. You are, however, required to assign to them before reading them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initial the total just declared.If the loop don't execute when total not equal any value because the variable(role) declared and initial int the loop.It better you declare and initial role before the loop.