# I have a problem with a java method return statement, I have given value for an un-initialized variable in an if-else statement

Tags: java, arraylist

```java
//Checks if a user exists in an ArrayList or not.

static String addUser(String x) {

    String output;

    for(int i = 0; i < usersArray.size(); i++) {
        if (usersArray.get(i).equals(x)) {
            output = String.format("User %s already exists!", x);
        } else{
            usersArray.add(x);
            output = String.format("User %s is added", x);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

If I initialize `output` at the start of the method `addUser`, it will only return that value whereas I want the value to switch depending on the condition.

Error statement: `Variable 'output' might not have been initialized`

Comment: "If I initialize "output" at the start of the method, it will only return that value" <- Thats not true. You can reassign new values to variables as often as you want when they are not final. So you could initialize it with `String output = null;` and if it later hits one of those `output = String.format("User %s is added", x);` new assignments the old null value will be replaced with the new one.

Comment: Just simply add `String output="";` It would work fine

Comment: I tried that but it's just printing "null" then.

Comment: Basically the if-else aren't affecting the output at all, they're just staying there with no help.

Comment: If-else wouldn't be in effect if your `usersArray` is empty and hence for-loop will have 0 iterations.

Comment: What would you like to return from the method if your usersArray.size() is 0? You need to initialize output  variable to that value. Local variables must be initialized to some value before used. Fields in the class have some default values but local variables don't.

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable might not have been initialized error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684905/variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
String checkUserExists(String x, List<String> usersArray) {
    String output;
    if(usersArray.contains(x)) {
        output = String.format("User %s already exists!", x);
    } else {
        usersArray.add(x);
        output = String.format("User %s is added", x);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked! Didn't expect to get an answer that quick tbh :) .

Answer (score 1):

You can use contains.

```
String addUser(List<String> users, String user) {
    if (users.contains(user)) {
        return String.format("User %s already exists!", user);
    } else {
        users.add(user);
        return String.format("User %s is added", user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your logic isn't correct at all.

You iterate your List and check if the current element of your iteration is equal to the user you want to add, if it is equal to the user you will set your output string and continue the iteration and if it isn't you add the new String to your list and continue with the iteration.

So lets say your list contains the Elements `["A", "B", "C"]` and you want to add `"A"`

1. Iteration will compare "A" to "A" and then set the String output to "User A already exists!"
2. Iteration will compare "B" to "A" and then add "A" to the list and set the output String to "User A is added"
3. Iteration will compare "C" to "A" and then add "A" to the list and set the output String to "User A is added"

So despite the fact that "A" was already in the list you have still added it twice and simply replaced the "already exists" message with a new one.

The error in your logic is that you cannot tell if your List already contains the item until you are completely done iterating it.

The other answers already gave you a solution with the List contains method, but here is a solution with a simple for-loop iteration:

```
static String addUser(String x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < usersArray.size(); i++) {
        if (usersArray.get(i).equals(x)) {
            // if we find that the user already is in the list we return immediately from the loop
            return String.format("User %s already exists!", x);
        } 
    }
    // if the loop finishes running the user to add wasn't found in the list
    usersArray.add(x);
    return String.format("User %s is added", x);

}
```

Comment: Yeah I see, so I shouldn't have added an else statement and just returned the string. Thanks!